# Converting unix time into datetime within csv

Tags: python, datetime, unix, time

i have a csv file with many lines and three column. first column is the unix time, second column the price, and third column  represents the volume of the symbol that has been traded at that specific price. what i'm doing is, calculating ohlc for different time frames (e.g. 1h, 4h, 12h, 1d) out of tha csv file. that is working very well by first converting the unix time into datetime

code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['date', 'price', 'volume'])
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('date')
df = df['price'].resample('4h').ohlc()
df.to_csv('file_4h_ohlc.csv')
```

result:

```
date,open,high,low,close
2017-05-01 20:00:00,0.757881,1.07,0.650011,1.069999
```

target:
i wanna now converte the datetime (2017-05-01 20:00:00) back to the unix time (1493658000) within the same file by keeping the ohlc values. or if not possible so, to save into a different file.
thanks a lot for support and sorry if such question has been already answered, but i didnt find it

-hotshot

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new date column instead of overwriting the existing one, so you can re-use it as the index.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['date', 'price', 'volume'])
df['datestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
df = df.set_index('datestamp')
df = df['price'].resample('4h').ohlc()

# Set the index back to the original (after calculating ohlc)
df = df.set_index('date')

# Optional: Drop the datestamp column
df = df.drop(columns=['datestamp'])

df.to_csv('file_4h_ohlc.csv')
```

Alternatively, you can convert the existing datetime column to a Unix timestamp like so:

```py
df['date'].apply(lambda x : (x - datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())
```

Comment: I think you could simplify the lambda function by `lambda x: x.timestamp()`?